# isinstance check of variable and module

Tags: python, class, inheritance, module, instance

I have a list of strings, which all are modules that are imported (I parsed the `__init__.py` file earlier for some other validation). For example `mods = ['mod_one', 'mod_two', 'mod_three']`. I now need to verify that all of these are an instance of a pre-defined superclass (*skeleton.py*) - like

```
for x in mods:
    if not isinstance(x.Operation,skeleton.OperationSkeleton): 
        print("error with: "+x)`
```

My problem is that x is in this case a string - obviously, but is the name of the imported module I want to check. The string doesn't have a `Operation`..

And odd enough.. for testing purpose did I try to

```
print(isinstance(mod_one.Operation,skeleton.OperationSkeleton))
```

and it prints `False`.
But in `mod_one.py` the `OperationSkeleton` is imported from `skeleton` and `class Clustering(ClusteringSkeleton):` is created.

Comment: `class Clustering` is not the same thing as `class.Operation`.

Comment: whoops. thanks for editing. But in *mod_one.py* the `OperationSkeleton` is imported from `skeleton` and `class Operation(OperationSkeleton):` is created.

Comment: Right, in which case `isinstance()` would just work. But do make sure you didn't accidentally added a package subdirectory to your path and imported the module under two different names (`package.module` and `module`), for example. You can verify you have the same class by looking at the `id(skeleton.OperationSkeleton)` and also look at `skeleton.__name__` and `skeleton.OperationSkeleton.__module__` in both locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your modules are already imported, you can access them by their name in the [`sys.modules` mapping](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules):

```
import sys

for x in mods:
    mod = sys.modules[x]
    if not issubclass(mod.Operation, skeleton.OperationSkeleton):
```

You need to use [`issubclass()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#issubclass) here as `Operation` is not an instance.

Comment: works perfectly fine! But I still get a `False` on `print(isinstance(sys.modules["my_modules.mod_one"].Operation, skeleton.OperationSkeleton))`

Comment: @DaedalusMythos: see my comment on your question; clearly you are not using the same class object to base the `Operation` class on as what you are using for `isinstance()`.

Comment: @DaedalusMythos: Another way you could introspect this is `sys.modules["my_modules.mod_one"].Operation.__bases__`; that is a tuple of base classes for `Operation`. Again look at things like the output of `id()` to see what objects are actually being used here.

Comment: I'm a little overwhelmed but grateful for the help! I learned that both `__name__`s use the `my_modules.` in front. But even if i `print(isinstance(sys.modules["my_modules.mod_one"].Operation, sys.modules["my_modules.skeleton"].OperationSkeleton)` it's `False`. What am I missing?

Comment: @DaedalusMythos: Sorry, I am being slow. You don't have an instance, you have a *class*, so use `issubclass()`.

Comment: perfect - `True` works now! You're not being slow, that helped a lot!